# Child selector from table

Tags: jquery, css, alert, html5, asseturlselector

```
<div class="content">
    <table id="Table" style="width: 100%;">
    </table>              
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="add()">Add row</button>


function add() {
$("#Table").append("<tr class=\"tr\">" +
    "<td class=\"col-xs-1\" ><h4><input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Skriv din Projekt kod här...\"    class=\"form-control Projrkt proj\"/></h4></td>" +
     "<td class=\"col-xs-1\" ><input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"2\" class=\"form-control Timmar\"/></td>" +
    "<td class=\"col-xs-1\" ><input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"2\" class=\"form-control Timmar\"/></td>" +
    "<td class=\"col-xs-1\" ><input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"2\" class=\"form-control Timmar\"/></td>" +
    "<td class=\"col-xs-1\" ><input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"2\" class=\"form-control Timmar\"/></td>" +
    "<td class=\"col-xs-1\" ><input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"2\" class=\"form-control Timmar\"/></td>" +
    "<td class=\"col-xs-1\" ><input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"2\" class=\"form-control Timmar\"/></td>" +
    "<td class=\"col-xs-1\" ><input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"2\" class=\"form-control Timmar\"/></td>" +
    "<td class=\"col-xs-1 tdStatus\"><h4><span \" class=\"lblStatus\"></span></h4></td>" +
    "<td class=\"col-xs-1 btnRaderaProjekt1\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger btn-xs RaderaProjekt\">Radera</button></td></tr>").trigger("create");
}

$(document).on("click", ".RaderaProjekt", function (e) {
    var x = $(e.target).parent().parent().children("td .Timmar:nth-child(2)").val();
    alert(x);
});
```

I want the value insde the text box that i chose

Comment: how this related to SharePoint?

Comment: This is just simple example to learn how to get value using selector. I have another code witch related to sharepoint list. I will ask it in my another question because your answer wan answer to my question but it wast exactly what i wanted

Comment: I think now you will understand me. I want the value insde the textbox that i chose

Comment: If I get thede values I will save them to my sharepoint list

Comment: Ok cool. I just wanted you to add more details so the question will be on topic and moderators will not mark it as off topic question

Comment: Can you help me with this new updated question?

Comment: Your question is not clear. How are you choosing textbox?

Comment: The value of input type text i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it like this

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn", function (e) {
    var x = $('.content > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)').text();
    alert(x);
});
```

Or you can use

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn", function (e) {    
    $('.content > table td').each(function(index){
        if(index == 4) alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```